# Php - регулярное выражение помогите)

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста
есть письма заголовки писем, подскажите как убрать Re[  ]: регулярным выражением php

Re: Новое письмо

```
Re[1]: Новое письмо
Re[2]: Новое письмо
Re[3]: Новое письмо
Re[4]: Новое письмо
```

Comment: Как вариант можно разбить функцией `explode()` по двоеточию, и удалить 1й элемент

Comment: Что вы уже сделали?

Comment: Я как раз использую explode но есть ошибки с ним) нужно полное удаление именно Re[-]

Comment: В приведённых вами входных данных не может быть ошибки с применением `explode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё удаляется, никаких проблем.

```
$str = 'Re[1]: Новое письмо';

$arr = explode(':', $str);
unset($arr[0]);

print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [1] =>  Новое письмо
)
```

C помощью регулярки:

```
$str = 'Re[1]: Новое письмо';

$string = preg_replace('/(Re)\[.*?\]:/','',$str);

echo $string;
```

Comment: Хорошо, а если какой нибудь клиент поставит : в заголовке письма? То опять ппц косяк будет)

Comment: @никита Вы удаляете только 1 элемент, остальное можете к примеру склеить, ну или сделать что вам требуется

Comment: А если это новое письмо оно идет без индекса Re[-] и и клиент в заголовке просто напиши "Ремонт машины : колеса" получается удалится часть заголовка. Я просто использую подобных способ, но он не решает задачу:( нужно именно регулярное выражение.

Comment: @никита, добавил регулярку конкретно для `Re`